# The filter is not deleting each item in array while clicking on button. please assist

Tags: reactjs, filter, react-hooks, setstate

The filter is not deleting each item in the array while clicking on the button. the id from onclick event is being received correctly. the first element is also being deleted then it's not deleting another element.

```
import React,{useState} from 'react'
    export default function Tour() {
        const tourPack=[
            {
                id:1,
                name:'a'           
            },
            {
                id:2,
                name:'k'
            },
            {
                id:3,
                name:'b'
            }
        ]
         const [TourPackage, setTourPackage] = useState(tourPack)
         const removeTour=(id)=>{//filtering functoin           
        const newTour=tourPack.filter((tour)=>tour.id!==id)
        console.log(newTour);
        setTourPackage(newTour)          
    }
        return (
            <div>
                <h1>{TourPackage.map((t)=>
                    <h1 key={t.id} >{t.name}<button onClick={()=>{removeTour(t.id)}}>Not interested!</button></h1>
                )}</h1>                   
            </div>
        )
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably are having this problem because you have two separate variables pointing to the array when you need only one. `tourPack` will be set to the default value every render cycle. And so will `tourPackage` because it is based on that.

```
import React,{useState} from 'react'
    export default function Tour() {
        
         const [TourPackage, setTourPackage] = useState([
            {
                id:1,
                name:'a'           
            },
            {
                id:2,
                name:'k'
            },
            {
                id:3,
                name:'b'
            }
        ]);
         const removeTour=(id)=>{//filtering functoin           
        const newTour=TourPackage.filter((tour)=>tour.id!==id)
        console.log(newTour);
        setTourPackage(newTour)          
    }
        return (
            <div>
                <h1>{TourPackage.map((t)=>
                    <h1 key={t.id} >{t.name}<button onClick={()=>{removeTour(t.id)}}>Not interested!</button></h1>
                )}</h1>                   
            </div>
        )
    }
```

Use only `TourPackage`.

Comment: where should i use TourPackage?

Comment: it is working. 
Thank you so much!

Comment: No issues. Please upvote(green tick) the answer to accept it. Consider upvoting.